# Can't import a 2nd mondgoDB collection to Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have an Node.JS/Express app holding a database with two main collections, named here as `first` and `second`. This database and its collections must be imported into MongoDB Atlas. Following the instructions available at Atlas, I proceeded the import of the collection `first` using `mongoimport` method. However, doing the *exact* same steps of the `first` collection, the `second` can't be imported by any means.

I downloaded a Terminal log to check ALL attempts I did for each one of them and tried to replicate the `first` success, but none worked. I even created a second account to watch it closer, but the behaviour is the same: `first` comes through, but `second` does not.

This is the code coming in (sensitive info swapped by CAPS words:

```
$usermac mongoimport --host flixNewMongoDB-shard-0/flixnewmongodb-shard-00-00-da9ev.mongodb.net:27017,flixnewmongodb-shard-00-01-da9ev.mongodb.net:27017,flixnewmongodb-shard-00-02-da9ev.mongodb.net:27017 --ssl --username admin --password PASSWORD --authenticationDatabase ADMINNAME --db DBNAME --collection COLLECTIONNAME --type json --file COLLECTIONNAME.json
```

This is the error message I receive in the end of the process:

```
2019-11-10T14:26:35.686+0100    Failed: open COLLECTIONNAME.json: no such file or directory
2019-11-10T14:26:35.686+0100    0 document(s) imported successfully. 0 document(s) failed to import.
```

My first doubt is why the code worked in the first attempt but not the second. All variables were the same. Could I have any insight of the friends here? Thanks in advance for the availability.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found for me: following the advice I received from Support, I exported the `second.json` collection and imported it manually. Once Atlas and my database were linked, it went through. I was uncertain about doing that because I was afraid to let the file without connection to the database, but that hasn't been the case.